# How to join two files with bash & remove duplicates?

Tags: linux, bash, join, text

I would like to know how to join two files on one column and remove the duplicates. Some examples first.

File1:

```
SERVER1; Deployed; Infrastructure
SERVER2; Deployed; Infrastructure
SERVER3; Deployed; Infrastructure
SERVER4; Deployed; Infrastructure
SERVER5; Deployed; Infrastructure
```

File2:

```
SERVER1;
SERVER2;
SERVER5;
```

Expectation:

```
SERVER3; Deployed; Infrastructure
SERVER4; Deployed; Infrastructure
```

Tried commands like: `sort File1 File2 | uniq > File3`, but it only returns me the joined output, as it does see every column as unique, output is like:

```
 SERVER1;
 SERVER1; Deployed; Infrastructure
 SERVER2;
 SERVER2; Deployed; Infrastructure
 SERVER3; Deployed; Infrastructure
 SERVER4; Deployed; Infrastructure
 SERVER5;
 SERVER5; Deployed; Infrastructure
```

Then tried to remove the duplicates from what I got above with command `awk -F";" '!_[$1]++' File3`, but seems like it only remove one duplicate line and left the other be:

```
SERVER1;
SERVER2;
SERVER3; Deployed; Infrastructure
SERVER4; Deployed; Infrastructure
SERVER5;
```

I would like to check on duplicates and remove both duplicate and the server itself, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: Hi jww, I think that I included both examples of commands I tried to launch and expected behavior (how I would like for it to work). I got the answers I need, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} !($1 in a)' File2  File1
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `grep` with the file (`-f`) and (`-v`) invert match options:

```
grep -vf File2 File1
```

**Output:**

```
SERVER3; Deployed; Infrastructure
SERVER4; Deployed; Infrastructure
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`join` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/join.1.html) works here:

```
$ join -t ';' -a 1 -v 2 File1 File2
SERVER3; Deployed; Infrastructure
SERVER4; Deployed; Infrastructure
```

join requires the files to be sorted. If they are not sorted:

```
$ join -t ';' -a 1 -v 2 <(sort File1) <(sort File2)
```